# How to do thousand comma separator for javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a thousand comma separator for JavaScript calculator.

But something works weird for me.

Here is the code that should work:

```js
var commas = result.textContent.toLocaleString("en-US");

var commas = result.textContent.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

result.innerHTML=commas;
```

It works only for 1st separator, but when it goes further it looks weird. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the screenshots:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS6BZ.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2K8k.png)

Here is the link to calculator:

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-rgb-2rp6dv?file=/js/script.js

**UPD: If there's more than 4 numbers it shows NaN:**
[NaN error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W36A.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add the HTML to the snippet so it doesn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Intl.NumberFormat`

```js
number = 100003.56
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(number));
```

Refer docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) for more

Comment: Thank you but now after it has more than 4 numbers it goes to NaN https://screenrec.com/share/3gKhWkQGVH